# Counting items in columns (Python Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count

With CSV file in Pandas, how do I count how many items in a column are more than a specified value?

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(20, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
     a   b   c
0   63  37  33
1   47  40  85
2   82  52   7
3   80  10  90
4   69  21  47
5   89  56  98
6   25  93  84
7   56  95  71
8   94  61  49
9   42  66  97
10  27  47  66
11  69  78  50
12  68   4  38
13  60  89  10
14  17  27  19
15  66  68  47
16  95  75  23
17  99  68  98
18  79  98  33
19  27  78  86

In [23]: df[['a','c']].gt(50).sum()
Out[23]:
a    14
c     9
dtype: int64

In [24]: df[['a','c']].gt(50)
Out[24]:
        a      c
0    True  False
1   False   True
2    True  False
3    True   True
4    True  False
5    True   True
6   False   True
7    True   True
8    True  False
9   False   True
10  False   True
11   True  False
12   True  False
13   True  False
14  False  False
15   True  False
16   True  False
17   True   True
18   True  False
19  False   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a DataFrame `df` with a numerical column named `value`. Here are some ways to count the number of elements of `value` that are greater than 3:

```
df[df.value > 3].shape[0]
len(df[df.value > 3])
df[df.value > 3].count()
```

Note that `shape` and `len` will count NaN values, whereas `count` will *exclude* NaN from the count.

Answer (score 0):

This question containing two part:

1. Read a CSV into data frame:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_csv('/where/ever/your/file/is/located')
   ```
2. Let say you've already have a data frame, then you can do:

   ```
   # selecting the rows on 'a' > 100
   df2 = df[df['a'] > 100 ]
   print(len(df2))
   ```